# Dynamically Split a table cell into multiple columns depending on the comma

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I have the following HTML Table displays data from the database.
The cell data use `btn btn-info` Bootstrap Button element to highlight the `Location Visited` Column.

> Current Table:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <table class="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                      <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                      <th scope="col">Location Visited</th>
                      <th scope="col">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">1</th>
                      <td>Mark</td>
                      <td>Otto</td>
                      <td> 
                          <span class="btn btn-info">
                                R-Block, S-Block, Audit-Block
                          </span>       
                        </td>
                        <td>June, 24, 2012</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">2</th>
                      <td>Jacob</td>
                      <td>Thornton</td>
                      <td> 
                          <span class="btn btn-info">
                               T-Block, S-Block, Finance-Block
                          </span>       
                        </td>
                         <td>January, 14, 2012</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="row">3</th>
                        <td>Parrel</td>
                        <td>Smith</td>
                      <td>
                          <span class="btn btn-info">
                                R-Block, H-Block,Admin-Block
                          </span>                       
                        </td>
                         <td>December, 04, 2012</td>
                    </tr>
                      
                  </tbody>
                 </table>
```

I want the Cell to always split data whenever a comma is loaded in the cell.

I Have tried using `Colspan` but I want the CELL Data to split into multiple columns automatically whenever a comma is present. e.g: if the cell has 2 commas columns, there must be two columns/(blocks), and if the cell has 3 commas the column/(blocks) has to be 3 as well.

> Desired Output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet

```js
let td = document.getElementById("container");
let string = "T-Block, S-Block, Finance-Block";
let newArray = string.split(",");

newArray.forEach(item => {
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-info me-1");
  span.innerHTML = item;
  td.appendChild(span);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Surname</th>
      <th scope="col">Location Visited</th>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td id="container"></td>
      <td>June, 24, 2012</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string into an array with

```
let newArray = string.split(",");
```

And then create a forEach(), like:

```
newArray.forEach( (item) => {
 let column = document.createElement('td');
 let block = document.createElement('span');
 block.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-info');
 block.innetHTML = item;
 column.appendChild(block);
 hereGoesTheRow.appendChild(column);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried your code unfortunately, it's a blank result. where does `hereGoesTheRow` come from? May you please use a `Snippet` for a better understanding